# Filling Javascript Chart (line chart) with SQL data

Tags: javascript, sql, .net

I'm using .NET MVC. Currently I have a data set that fills in points for a JS chart. Currently, I have static data(numbers) in the data property of the data set.  I'm looking for idea's, tutorials, how-to's, on how to fill the data property with data from my SQL DB. I've looked all over and see numerous tutorials with static data like I have.

```
var ctx2 = document.getElementById("totalSpendingChart");
    var data2 = {
        datasets: [{
            label: "Spending",
            data: [8,10,11,15], /* THIS.. how do I get SQL data here? */
            borderColor: "#e8144d"
        }],
        labels: [ "2017", "2018", "2019"]
    };

 var LinChart1 = new Chart(ctx2, {
        type: "line", data: data2, options: {
            pointStyle: "circle",
            legend: { display: false },
            scales: { yAxes: [{ display: true, gridLines: { display: true } }], xAxes: [{ display: false, gridLines: { display: false } }] }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You somehow need to get the data from the backend (SQL) to the frontend (JavaScript).

**Option 1**

You could inject the data into your template (before you render the chart). For example by [serializing your data to JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/json-serialization) and parse it using javascript:

```
<script>
var chartData = JSON.parse(<%= DataSet %>);
</script>
```

**Option 2**

You could create an endpoint (url to fetch the data from) which can be used in javascript with an [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) get request. Once the data is loaded you can render the chart:

```
$.ajax("https://your-endpoint-to-fetch-the-data")
  .done(renderChart);

function renderChart(data) {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("totalSpendingChart");

  var chartData = {
    datasets: [{
      data: data,
      // ...
    }]
  };

  var lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // ...
  });
};
```

(this example uses jQuery for the ajax part)

Comment: thanks. I've seen similar solutions around. My knowledge utilizing this format is poor. Guess, it's a good time to dive in.

Comment: I've added an alternative option, hope it helps. My .net is poor so not totally sure about that part.

Comment: Appreciate the help. I'm going to spend some time working through the example you provided. I'll certainly give it an up vote upon my success of it.